# How to fix: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_updatedFibers' on number '0' in react?

Tags: reactjs

How to fix: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_updatedFibers' on number '0' in react?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_updatedFibers' on number '0'
at requestUpdateLane (react-dom.development.js:25307:1)
at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:28763:1)
at ReactDOMRoot.ReactDOMHydrationRoot.render.ReactDOMRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:29216:1)
at Module../src/index.js (index.js:15:1)
at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at startup:7:1
at startup:7:1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVFYK.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your packages are upToDate with the latest react.

you can update using the following example:

```
 yarn add react@latest react-dom@latest boostrap@latest ....so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on the other comments check also if you have any resolutions for react, I had to update those too.