# react error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_updatedFibers' on number '0'

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

react biginer error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_updatedFibers' on number '0' need help
don't know why this happen need any help.
this is my first react project so i couldn't understand

followins are error code then i write my codes

```
react-dom.development.js:25417 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_updatedFibers' on number '0'
    at requestUpdateLane (react-dom.development.js:25417:1)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:28815:1)
    at ReactDOMHydrationRoot.render.ReactDOMRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:29314:1)
    at ./src/index.js (index.js:9:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1
```

where i post my error codes
https://jsfiddle.net/bq6yds25/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '\_updatedFibers' on number '0' in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400715/how-to-fix-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-create-property-updatedfibers-on-numbe)